# Error Description in XAML WP8

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have this warning in my WP8 project, but it doesn't harm the program. Could you tell me what is that?

```
Warning The predefined type 'System.Tuple' is defined in multiple assemblies in the global alias; using definition from 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.0\mscorlib.dll'    C:\Users\Rony Fhebrian Yusuf\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Help!\Help!\CSC
```

Comment: You have two assemblies which define the same type System.Touple and program informs you which of those will be used.

Answer (score 0):

As Romasz said, you probably have more than one assemblies which define the same Type.

To remove any possible ambiguity, you could use the Type using its full Path, ex: 'A.B.C.TheType'.